# Python text-based rpg class-stats

Tags: python, pygame, rpgmakermv

So my problem is, that I need stats for my classes but have no idea ho to assign them in a way that it makes sense. 
I have following stats: HP, Atk, Def, Sp-Atk, Sp-Def, Spd, Agi, Acc (all stats reach from 0-100) (pretty similar as pokemon I know)
I have following classes:
Knight: physical attack class with a two-handed sword.
 It deals little aoe dmg and massive single target dmg
Mage: special assist class with a staff.
 It uses spells to deal aoe dmg and heal
Assassin: special attack with two daggers.
 It casts dark spells to avoid dmg and deals great single target dmg
Archer: physical assist with a bow.
 It uses arrows to suppress enemys and make them more vulnerable to dmg and deals dmg over time
Dragon: special tank with metal gloves.
 It uses spells and his fists to deal massive aoe dmg and great single target dmg.
 Also it can summon a shield to protect allies.
Paladin: physical tank with a shield and single-handed sword.
 It uses his shield to gain def points and does moderate aoe dmg
It would be nice if you could tell me where I get a stat chart for something like this or a rpg class-stat generator. 
[the code I have so far:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICbIW.png)

Comment: either create `@property`(properties) for that class or add attributes like this (in the constructor method): `self.dmg = some_int`, but actually You should provide some code: [mre]

Comment: So you are building an RPG type game engine from scratch…? +1 @Matiss. Need minimum example code.

Comment: @WingTangWong Yes, I just have no idea which values to use. \n
`import health as h` <br>
`import damage as d`<br>
`import numpy as np`<br>

`class properties(self):`<br>
    `self.hp = hp`<br>
    `self.atk = atk`<br>
    `self.def = def`<br>
    `self.spatk = spatk`<br>
    `self.spdef = spdef`<br>
    `self.spd = spd`<br>
    `self.agi = agi`<br>
    `self.acc = acc`<br><br>

`def choose_class():`<br>
    `player_classes = np.array(["Knight", "Mage", "Assassin", "Archer", "Dragon", "Paladin"])`<br><br>

`d.do_damage(20)`

Comment: Is there a reason you are employing numpy’s data structures over say… creating a class and the relevant object methods?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you've tagged your question as RPG Maker by mistake. But still I recommend you to read this book. Some concepts could be useful in your project.

Perez D. - Beginning RPG Maker MV, 2nd  Edition (Expert's Voice in Game Development)